# Why does com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer hang?

Tags: java, https, freeze

When my simple HTTPS server implemented using `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer` is called via [this PHP proxy](https://languagetool.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/languagetool/trunk/website/www/online-check/tiny_mce/plugins/atd-tinymce/server/proxy.php) (which uses curl), it works fine. But as soon as I don't use the proxy but change my web form so that browsers directly send their requests to the server, the server becomes unstable and sometimes stops responding. The client will then wait for a response until it times out. The problem is difficult to reproduce and sometimes happens after hours in the live system. All of this is via HTTPS, on a non-standard port (currently 8081). My server returns XML.

The stacktrace I see when the server doesn't respond anymore (via "`kill -QUIT [pid]`"):

```
"Thread-2" prio=10 tid=0x0000000017fc4800 nid=0x1c2b runnable
    [0x00002ba5ec97c000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:218)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:191)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:359)
    - locked <0x00000000fd1e4b98> (a java.lang.Object)
at sun.net.httpserver.SSLStreams$EngineWrapper.recvAndUnwrap(SSLStreams.java:334)
    - locked <0x00000000fd1e4c58> (a java.lang.Object)
at sun.net.httpserver.SSLStreams.recvData(SSLStreams.java:409)
at sun.net.httpserver.SSLStreams$InputStream.read(SSLStreams.java:524)
at sun.net.httpserver.SSLStreams$InputStream.read(SSLStreams.java:593)
at sun.net.httpserver.Request.readLine(Request.java:84)
at sun.net.httpserver.Request.<init>(Request.java:54)
at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:529)
at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$DefaultExecutor.execute(ServerImpl.java:156)
at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Dispatcher.handle(ServerImpl.java:424)
at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Dispatcher.run(ServerImpl.java:389)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

**What I already tried:** Sending a `Connection: close` http header - didn't help. Writing a Java test case that uses multiple threads to query the server in parallel - works fine.

So the questions is: what do browsers do different than my proxy, and why does that make my server process hang?

**Source:** here's [the source of the HttpHandler](https://languagetool.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/languagetool/trunk/languagetool/languagetool-server/src/main/java/org/languagetool/server/LanguageToolHttpHandler.java) and here's [the source of the Server that uses that handler](https://languagetool.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/languagetool/trunk/languagetool/languagetool-server/src/main/java/org/languagetool/server/HTTPSServer.java)

**Background:** I want anybody to be able to use my REST service from their web page, without installing a proxy (needed to circumvent the Javascript cross-origin policy). For that, the server sends an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header. I'm using the classes provided by Java to have minimal overhead compared to Jetty or Tomcat Embedded.

Comment: Which type/version of OS and JVM do you using on server side?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS, Java is 1.7.0_07 - Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM

Comment: Some code please.  Can't really diagnose without it.  :^)

Comment: @glen-best I have added links to the source code.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I've since trawled through the API and discovered that by default there are long timeouts on server socket requests and responses (set in ServerConfig class) - which would be more of a problem without the proxy, because the number of greater number of connections.  The API gives no way to programmatically change them, but you can change via JVM system properties - see my answer post.

Comment: Have you considered extending an existing web server implementation like Jetty? (I don't know if it's the best available, it's just an example)

Answer (score 9):

### Why different behaviour for proxy & no proxy?

- more connections with no proxy
- real-world browser users can do funny things, like start a request and then cancel/back button/new request.

You need to set a socket timeout.  Unfortunately, the API documentation suggests no way to do so programmatically.

### But you can set resquest & response timeouts via JVM system properties:

http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/8424
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/net/httpserver/ServerConfig.java
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6563368

Set these system properties:

**sun.net.httpserver.clockTick**     Default value = 10000 i.e. 10 sec

**sun.net.httpserver.timerMillis**     Default value = 1000 i.e. 1 sec

**sun.net.httpserver.maxReqTime**      Default value = -1 i.e. forever.

A default > 0 gives timeout = default * (either clockTick ot timerMillis) sec

**sun.net.httpserver.maxRspTime**     Default value = -1 i.e. forever.

A default > 0 gives timeout = default * (either clockTick ot timerMillis) sec

---

Obviously, in your HttpHandler.handle() method, make sure you set the response code in the response headers:

```
  httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK, response.length());  
  final OutputStream os = httpExchange.getResponseBody();  
  os.write( response.getBytes() );  
  os.close();
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm now using `-Dsun.net.httpserver.maxReqTime=60000 -Dsun.net.httpserver.maxRspTime=60000` on the live system. I'll add another comment whether it works in some days.

Comment: The result is, unfortunately, that it doesn't work: the server sometimes hangs for about 5 minutes, then continues. The client will wait that long for the result. After that, everything works fine until the next hang.

Comment: If you're using default values for clockTick & timerMillis, then you should set timeouts to either 30 or 3 to get 30 sec timeout on both request & response.  Cheers

Comment: I'm sorry I can't quite follow: wouldn't that mean that the hangs just get shorter? The usual response time of my service is less than one second, so a 30-second freeze would not be acceptable. I should also have mentioned that all of this also happens under low load - the server only gets about 100 requests per hour.

Comment: No. Should mean no hangs or very long non-responsive waits at all.  I suspect your server stops responding when all threads are busy reading from socket, waiting on input, but no more input comes from browser. E.g. browser back button/close/cancel.  Suggested settings should mean threads reading from sockets timeout in a reasonable time, becoming available to actually process new user requests.  i.e. big change in the balance between threads in the pool busy waiting on read, and threads available for processing.  Note the default settings mean infinite waiting - i.e. a true 'hang'.

Comment: maxRspTime and maxReqTime set to 30 or 10 helps a lot, but they don't completely solve the problem, i.e. hangs are shorter and less frequent. I currently suspect SSL to be the problem, e.g. I cannot test my service with a monitoring website like pingdom, because my service doesn't accept SSLv2 requests, only SSLv3. The same problem might occur be with some browsers.

Comment: what are the clocktick and timermillis parameters for ?

Comment: Looking in source code for sun.net.httpserver.ServerConfig.java and ServerImpl.java:  clockTick = time unit applied against other parameters (acts like a multiplier);  timerMillis = time period between each execution of the timer task which checks timeouts (granularity against which timeouts are checked).   If you specify maxReqTime, then timeout t in millisecs will be in range:  maxReqTime*clockTick < t < (maxReqTime+timerMillis)*clockTick.   Same for maxRsTime.  Lower granularity (smaller timerMillis), means a little more thread processing to check timeouts, with resulting extra accuracy. :)

Comment: What we also do now is to use ```HttpServer.setExecutor()``` to set an executor with 10 threads. The default seems to be to only use 1 Thread.

Comment: `-Dsun.net.httpserver.maxRspTime=60000` the unit is second not millisecond.  see source code https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/dc08216f0ef55970c96df43bcc86ebd5792d486e/src/jdk.httpserver/share/classes/sun/net/httpserver/ServerImpl.java#L110-L110